# Counting instances of a value and ignoring consecutive repetitions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a **df** with one column (*pos*):

```
       pos      
0      d  
1      V  
2      V      
3      n   
4      V  
5      b
```

I would like to count the value **V** every time it appears and just **ONCE** if it appears in consecutive rows, so that it would result in a new column (*v_count*) like the following:

```
       pos      v_count
0      d           0
1      V           1
2      V           0     
3      n           0   
4      V           1
5      b           0
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want a 1 if and only if you get a `'V'` in a row and not in the previous one. So you can do:

```
df['v_count'] = ((df['pos']=='V')&(df['pos'].shift()!='V')).astype('int')
```

It gives as expected:

```
  pos  v_count
0   d        0
1   V        1
2   V        0
3   n        0
4   V        1
5   b        0
```